# Only open accordion once, but still call onclick each time, when button clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery accordion animation:

```
$('.accordion').click(function() {
       $(this).next().toggle("fold", 1000);
       return false;
  }).next().hide();
```

along with a button for expanding the div below:

```
<button class="accordion" onclick="my_method()">EXPAND</button>
    <div  class="panel">
        ...contents to expand here
    </div>
```

This works great. But I only want to allow the accordion to open once (unless page refreshed obviously), although the onclick event should call the method every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

```
$('.accordion').one('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggle("fold", 1000);
  return false;
}).next().hide();
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/xOPGzR)

Comment: It acts the same. It opens and closes with the same animation.

Comment: I added Codepen example.